# Sudden error in workspace while working with android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

My eclipse is having an issue. Suddenly whilst developing an android app with the SDK I encountered an error saying "periodic workspace save has encountered an error"
the error details is as follows. any ideas?

```
Could not write metadata for '/.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders'.
    D:\Android\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders\.markers.snap (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Save your work to the cloud or external.  Reboot wish for the best.

Comment: I had this problem when I deleted the .org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders from my Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\ folder.  I had this still in my Trash so was able to reinstate from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the workspace permission and restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workspace(later u can delete it). Switch to the new workspace. refresh the eclipse(file->refresh). Now switch back to ur old workspace(file->switch workspace) and refresh it. This technique worked for me(Eclipse Juno).